# linux mint ulimit configuration

Tags: ulimit

In my Linux Mint desktop, `ulimit -Hs` shows values greater than `fs.file-max`. As far as I know it should be smaller values than the system-wide settings. Is this OK for Debian-based systems or do I have some bad configuration?

```
~ $ ulimit -Hn
1048576
 ~ $ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
785776
```